# How to inherit interface from generics in Kotlin?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, kotlin

I'm said to have `PersonImpl<Base : IPerson>` generics class, where `IPerson` is interface of Person.
I'm trying to do this

```
interface IPerson {
    fun getName(): String
}

interface IPoliceMan : IPerson {
    fun getDepartmentName(): String
}

open class PersonImpl<T: IPerson>(private val name: String) : T
```

and then

```
class PoliceMan(private val departmentName: String, name: String) : PersonImpl<IPoliceMan>(name)
```

So I want the compiler to say I need to implement  `getDepartmentName()` in `PoliceMan`, but this is not possible as *Only classes and interfaces may serve as supertypes*

So the only variant is like this

```
class PoliceMan(private val departmentName: String, name: String) : IPoliceMan, PersonImpl<IPoliceMan>(name)
```

with interface duplication.

**Can I have generic supertype in Kotlin (or Java)?**

P.S. If it's not possible, is there any mechanism of emulating this behaviour?

Comment: Forcing a class to implement a method is not the purpose of generics, that's what extending abstract classes and/or implementing interfaces are for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need generics for this, just implementing interfaces.

```
interface IPerson { // "HasName"
    val name: String
}

interface IPoliceMan : IPerson { // "HasDepartmentName"
    val departmentName: String
}

open class Person(
    override val name: String
) : IPerson

class PoliceMan(
    override val departmentName: String, 
    name: String
) : Person(name), IPoliceMan
```

Comment: Yeah, obviously this is clear variant, but I was said to implement like it was in question (the task is based on C++, where it's possible to inherit from template)

Comment: I don't think you can do that in Kotlin.

Comment: I agree that you can't do that in Kotlin.  In C++ (as I understand it), generics are implemented with templates, so each instantiation can have a different superclass.  Whereas in Kotlin (and Java), generics are implemented using type erasure; as far as the runtime is concerned, there's only a single class, and so it can only have one superclass.